# Strange behaviour with relative and absolute paths in Chrome extension popup

Tags: html, google-chrome-extension

My chrome extension's popup html is treating paths to JS and CSS files as if they are relative to the html's parent folder, but other types of files as if they are relative to the parent's parent folder.

This is my folder structure:

```
 root
  ↳ manifest.json
  ↳  assets
     ↳ popup.html
     ↳  css
     ↳  js
     ↳  images
     ↳  fonts
```

Inside popup.html, tags like these work fine:

```
<link href="css/popup.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/popup.js"></script>
```

But this one fails with a net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

```
<img src="images/example_image.svg">
```

What's strange is that if I change the image path to:

```
<img src="assets/images/example_image.svg">
```

^this works, but I have no idea why, because the path should be relative to the same directory the CSS and JS files are.

I've checked and rechecked 100 times, and there is no issue with the file names, and the folder structure is exactly as it should be.

Comment: If this is the contents of the final compiled file then it's a bug in Chrome. If this is the source html file then your compiler must be changing the URLs of images.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question: For some reason the problem was resolved when I placed the contents of files/ directly in the root folder. I guess chrome extensions have some kind of bug with nested directories